# Kivy asyncio and open_settings()

Tags: kivy, python-asyncio, settings

I am trying to work out how to do an open_settings() from a Kivy App that has been created using asyncio.

As expected, this doesn't work:

```
Button:
            text:"Open Settings"
            on_release: app.open_settings()
```

I get the error:

```
Exception:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

The App is instantiated with the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def root_func():
        """
        This will run both methods asynchronously and then block until they're finished
        """
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)  # root widget
        websocket_receiver_task = asyncio.ensure_future(websocket_receiver(root))
        process_queued_log_task = asyncio.ensure_future(queue_processor(root))
        return asyncio.gather(ExampleViewer.kivy_runner(root, websocket_receiver_task, process_queued_log_task), websocket_receiver_task, process_queued_log_task)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(root_func())
    loop.close()
```

The ExampleViewer code is:

```
class ExampleViewer(BoxLayout):
    """
    This class, which runs Kivy, is run by the asyncio loop as one of the coroutines.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleViewer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    async def kivy_runner(self, websocket_receiver_task, process_queued_log_task):
        try:
            print("Starting kivy.")
            await async_runTouchApp(self)  # run Kivy
            print('App terminated.')

            # cancel all the other tasks that may be running
            websocket_receiver_task.cancel()
            process_queued_log_task.cancel()

        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Exception:\n{exc}")
```

Suggestions as how to launch settings would be gratefully received. :)

I have tried googling for suggestions but have come up blank. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have an `App` instance, I don't think you can call the `open_settings()` method. However, if you look at the `asyncio_advanced.py` code in the Kivy examples, it shows how to run an async app with an actual `App` instance. Perhaps you can modify your code to work that way.